# Prevent current user from seeing their record? VPD - ORACL12C

Tags: oracle, security, oracle12c, vpd

I am trying to create a function that will prevent the current logged in user from viewing their own record in the scott.emp table.

I have written a function to enforce the policy. Currently the return statement is `return 'ename != CURRENT_USER';` however this does not work.

I'm not sure if I have to add a new function parameter or if I just need to change the return statement. Putting multiple quotes in the return statement compiles the function with errors. Is there formatting I'm missing?

```
create or replace function self(
    p_schema in varchar2,
    p_object in varchar2)
return varchar2 as
begin
    return 'ename != CURRENT_USER';
end;
/

begin
    dbms_rls.add_policy
    (object_schema => 'SCOTT',
    object_name => 'EMP',
    policy_name => 'self',
    policy_function => 'self');
end;
/
```

Comment: `self` is a keyword - it's used in Types. Although Oracle allows us to use it, a different name would be better. How about `not_self` (which is also truer)?

Comment: @APC you're right, need to work on naming conventions lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "my function return statement is ... however this does not work"

Your current function is returning a fixed string. Unless your table has a column called `CURRENT_USER` it's always going to throw a runtime error.

> "Putting multiple quotes in the return statement compiles the function with errors."

You don't say what errors you get but I'm guessing `ORA-00984: column not allowed here`. That's because `current_user()` is not a valid Oracle database function (I think it's supported in JDBC but that is different).

What you need is USER. Try this function, it will work for you:

```
create or replace function banself(
    p_schema in varchar2,
    p_object in varchar2)
return varchar2 as
begin
    return 'ename != USER';
end;
/
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I would just like to note it also works as just 'ename != USER'; 

And you're right I should've shown the errors, completely forgot about checking them, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_USER is accessible with  sys_context ('userenv', 'current_user') or function DBMS_UTILITY.OLD_CURRENT_USER.

You have to change your return statment  to. 
  `return 'ename != DBMS_UTILITY.OLD_CURRENT_USER ';`
or 
  `return 'ename != sys_context (''userenv'', ''current_user'') ';`

Comment: I see... What does the 'userenv' parameter represent btw?

Comment: `Userenv` is predefined namespace of oracle context. The context is set of name-value paris that db stores in memory. `SYS_CONTEXT` returns the value of parameter associated with the context `namespace`. Furthermore you can create own context . [create context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_5002.htm#SQLRF01202)